# Which authorization bundle can I use in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony

can you recommend me some Authorization bundle to Symfony 3. I know there is a tutorial in Symfony 3 book but I'm looking for stable and secure bundle.

Comment: I did use FOS bundle and it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOS bundle is here available For Authorization in Symfony 3. For more information visit here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I can see in documentation this bundle is available for Symfony 2.1+. Did you check it on Symfony 3?

Comment: FOS v2.0.* or v2.0.x will work with Symfony 3.0.1 and for getting latest version of FOS bundle u can use in your composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0.x", the good thing of Symfony3 is that it supports V2 components  also, so no worry you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the cookbook: 
**composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0@dev"** works fine.